# Redis: ERR hash value is not an integer

Tags: node.js, redis

Sometimes i am getting following error while trying to increment value in hash field.

```
{ ReplyError: ERR hash value is not an integer
at parseError (/opt/node-app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)
at parseType (/opt/node-app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
command: 'HINCRBY',
args: [ 'users:5b0598cd2f197a557e13e9d5', 'nTotalChips', 700 ],
code: 'ERR' }
```

My code is as follows:

```
redisClient.hincrby("users:5b0598cd2f197a557e13e9d5", "nTotalChips", 700, function(err, nTotalChips) {
    //some other logic        
});
```

I got some hint by reading that this is error due to serialization, but i didnt got where exactly it is because this error not generated all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ERR hash value is not an integer

This is an error when you are trying to increment a hash field that's NOT an integer.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset hash field 1
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hincrby hash field 2            // OK
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> hset hash field string-value
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hincrby hash field 2            // ERROR
(error) ERR hash value is not an integer
```

It seems that some other client changed the hash field to a string value.

Comment: Yeah, there may be chance let me check that

Comment: Thanks man, i got the accidentally i that value converted to float and that was giving that value.